# Gradle Build error while using Sonarqube local-plugin from file system

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle

I am trying to use the plugin for sonarqube scanner in my gradle build . Due to the certificate issue It can neither be downloaded from the internet nor from the Nexus repository where the other plugins are usually placed in our environment.

- Gradle Version : 4.1.10
- Sonar Plugin - 3.1

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
      classpath files ("../../thirdparty/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.1")
                 }
             }

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

While executing the build, I am getting the error :

> line: 12 * What went wrong:\n
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'custom-extensions'.\n>
> Plugin with id 'org.sonarqube' not found.

am I doing it correctly and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

According to the plugin [documentation](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube/3.1) and the description of a [flat directory resolver](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/repository_types.html) I would make it like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    flatDir {
      dirs "../../thirdparty/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.1"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

Edit:

`sonarqube-gradle-plugin` depends on `sonar-scanner-api` and both of them need to be loaded. When using a `flatDir` resolver, POMs are not consulted and this dependency cannot be discovered automatically. In this case you would need to explicitly depend on `sonar-scanner-api` as well:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    flatDir {
      dirs "thirdparty/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.1"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.1"
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.api:sonar-scanner-api:2.16.0.226"
  }
}
```

Your 3rd party directory would need to include both jars; POMs are not needed since they are not consulted anyway:

```
$ find thirdparty/ -type f
thirdparty/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.1/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.0.226.jar
thirdparty/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.1/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.1.jar
```

As an alternative approach you can recreate Maven hierarchy locally so that dependencies are parsed automatically. This includes more directories and files, but can be easier to maintain in the long run (if any new dependencies arise it would be sufficient to update the directory contents without altering `build.gradle`):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "file://${projectDir}/thirdparty"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.1"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

This would require to recreate all the required files and directories:

```
$ find thirdparty/ -type f
thirdparty/org/sonarsource/parent/parent/55/parent-55.pom
thirdparty/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.0.226/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.0.226.jar
thirdparty/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.0.226/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.0.226.pom
thirdparty/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api-parent/2.16.0.226/sonar-scanner-api-parent-2.16.0.226.pom
thirdparty/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/3.1/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.1.jar
thirdparty/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/3.1/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-3.1.pom
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , I am getting error while I run with above build.gradle :

Comment: * What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'custom-extensions'.
  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.sonarqube']
 > Could not create task ':sonarqube'.
  > Could not generate a proxy class for class org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.